# Questions on building a very basic compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, bytecode

For fun and practice, I want to build a very simple programming language and compiler (using Java). I will describe my design idea, and then ask a number of questions about it. Will appreciate your help :)

**The design:**

The programs written with this language would run on a (simple of course) Virtual Machine I will create.

The steps for writing and running a program:

1 - The programmer writes the code in the compiler (a kind of IDE).
    **Compilation happens as follows:**

- The compiler scans the code, and converts each line to op-code. For example, if the line  of code is: `print ("hello")`, the compiler will convert it to something like `p"hello"` - this would be
  the op-code.
- After scanning the entire code, we'll have a Bytecode file, composed of all the op-codes generated.

  This Bytecode type will be created by me for my VM. This won't be Bytecode in the tehnical definition, in the sense that it's op-codes won't be one byte each. Instead, each op-code will be an instruction combining letters and numbers. (Like in my example: the op-code `p"hello"` tells the VM to print "Hello" to the screen). It is Bytecode in the sense that it is the result of compiling programming-language code, and it is code be executed by the VM (correct?).

2 - **Running the program (executing the Bytecode) is done as follows:**

- The program runs inside the Virtual Machine program. This program
  will scan the Bytecode loaded into it, and convert each op-code to some Java
  operation (since the VM program will be written in Java). For
  example, the VM will read the op-code `p"hello"`, and in reaction
  execute: `System.out.println("hello");`.

**My questions**

- **Is this VM program considered a VM?**
- **Is this Bytecode considered Bytecode?** (Even though it's not written in the professional way, where each op-code is one byte)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both questions (off-topic on stackoverflow):

> Is this VM program considered a VM?

Yes, a [(process) virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) is something interpreting some low-level representation like a bytecode

> Is this Bytecode considered Bytecode?

Yes, [byte-codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) are not always one byte each.

I strongly recommend reading Queinnec's [Lisp in small pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_In_Small_Pieces)

Comment: The one byte each thing is a red herring. Yes, a byte code can (and usually does) have more than one byte per instruction; but the problem here isn't the number of bytes, it's that the code is in plaintext - not a binary format (unless I misunderstood the OP). That makes it source code and his "VM" an interpreter.

Comment: @sepp2k That indeed makes it not bytecode, but a VM that executes bytecode is also an interpreter by all but the most stupidly restrictive definitions.

Comment: @sepp2k So what do I need to do, in order to make my compiled code Bytecode and not source code? Do I need to convert it to binary? What are the advantages of doing so? I need my VM program to read code and execute what it says to do. What are the advantages of making it binary and not plain text? The result is the same, isn't it|?

Comment: Read Queinnec's book (or some other good book about compilers, interpreters, virtual machines, bytecodes). I cannot explain that in a few minutes. You need many hours of reading and learning.